# Spring - return my onw exception in my own annotation used for validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-validator

I have my onw annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {MaxDateValidator.class})
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MaxDate {
```

and my validator:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MaxDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxDate, LocalDate> {


    @Override
    public void initialize(MaxDate constraintAnnotation) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(LocalDate date, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
      //I want to throw my onw exception here with some hint to be read by 
      frontend
      if(condition){
         throw new MyException("message", HINTS.WRONG_DATE);
      }
      return someCondition();
    }
}
```

My question is if it's possible to throw my own exception in isValid method? I have my own annotation @MaxDate set on some field in my Dto coming from frontend and in some cases I'd like to throw here my own exception with some hint to be read by frontend and displaying some validation message.

Or maybe I should completely remove this annotation and do some validation in my service method?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to throw your own exception from the `isValid` method because by the contract this method shouldn't throw any exceptions (and should be threadsafe by the way). To customize the exception thrown by this validator you can use standard mechanisms like:

1. Add `String message() default "your message";` field inside MaxDate annotation.
2. Use ConstraintValidatorContext like this:

> ```
> if(condition){
>      context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
>      context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Your message").addConstraintViolation();
>      return false;
> }
> ```